# trying to delete an item from a list of items

Tags: reactjs, django

I am trying to delete an item from a list of items, but it deletes all the items in the list when page loads, i am sure its because of the map, i cant think of a way to fix this without making a detail page for the todos but i dont want to make a detail page for the todo item, any help will be appreciated

```
 let deleteTodo = async(id) => {
    console.log(id)
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/delete/${id}/`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    })
  }

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div>

          
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Title:
              <input type="text" placeholder='Title here' onChange={handleInputChange} name="title" value={values.title} />
            </label>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <label>
              Body:
              <input type="text" placeholder='Body here' onChange={handleInputChange} name="body" value={values.body} />
            </label>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>

        </div>

        <div>
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <h1>{todo.title}</h1>
              <h4>{todo.body}</h4>
              <button onClick={deleteTodo(todo.id)}>delete</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button callback is immediately invoked upon rendering.

```
<button onClick={deleteTodo(todo.id)}>delete</button>
```

Should be called in a callback handler function.

```
<button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>delete</button>
```

Or make `deleteTodo` a curried function so it's immediately invoked and closes over the passed `id` value and returns a function to be called when button is clicked.

```
const deleteTodo = (id) => () => {
  console.log(id);
  fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/delete/${id}/`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  })
};

...

<button onClick={deleteTodo(todo.id)}>delete</button>
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked, can you help me with another thing, i have to reload page to show changes how can i fix that

Comment: @isabella-re You can either refetch the data and update local state, or see if the `"/api/delete/:id"` endpoint returns the updated data, or if it doesn't `await` the DELETE request to succeed and delete it from your local state yourself. Do these make sense?

Comment: i am sorry but i am still a bit confused about how to do it

Comment: i called getTodos at the end of  deleteTodo but it still isnt working

Comment: @isabella-re This follow-on line of questions regarding the issue of getting the updated todos locally is actually a bit off-topic for the specific question you asked about the callback immediately taking effect. It would be better if you created a new post on SO for this new specific issue you want to ask about. With it you can include the callback handlers that get and delete the data and we'll have better context for the data wrangling you are attempting. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here in comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.